# Pick random path from CSV file in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I want to perform a load test with JMeter on our API using HTTP requests. I have 40 endpoints in a CSV file and there will be much more requests than just 40 (during 5 minute run it can be 100 000 requests).

**My CSV file looks like this:**

channels,/channels

pages,/pages

sites,/sites

.

36 more endpoints

.

seos,/seos

Is it possible to force JMeter to select the path from CSV file randomly?

**Example**

1. request ... pick endpoint */pages* and send GET request
2. request ... pick endpoint */seos* and send GET request
3. request ... pick endpoint */sites* and send GET request
4. request ... pick endpoint */pages* (AGAIN) and send GET request

etc. for more than 100 000 times in 5 minutes.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think jmeter natively support random csv data read, you can try with this plugin: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-the-random-csv-data-set-config-plugin-on-jmeter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should be doing this as well-behaved test should be [repeatable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeatability), however if you're absolutely sure that you need this functionality you can go for one of the following plugins:

- [Random CSV Data Set Config](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/random-csv-data-set/RandomCSVDataSetConfig.md)
- [HTTP Simple Table Server](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/)

Both can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)

Comment: I used Random CSV Data Set Config and it did the job. Thank you.